# Uniqueness algorithm can be solved by the closest pair algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

My professor told us in class today that if we can solve the closest pair problem in O(f(n)) time then we can solve the uniqueness problem, too. I know that this has to do with the fact that in the closest pair problem we can check whether the min distance is 0, and if it is then we don't have all unique items, but how can this be done in O(f(n))?

Answer (score 0):

She didn't say it *could* be done in O(f(n)) (although without defining f, *anything* is O(f(n))); she said *if* closest-pair could be solved in O(f(n)), then so could uniqueness (if think; your wording is a bit vague on that point).  As you say, you can check the min distance; if it is 0, then there are at least 2 non-unique items, otherwise not.  Presumably that check is O(1), so however fast you can solve closes-pairs, you can solve uniqueness just as quickly.

Comment: Is there a way to define f and prove this? We haven't covered this in class, but I'm curious about using it for my final class project.